# In this sentence, is "much" an ellipsis of "much of you"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, ellipses

> "Are you sure that your men will find **much** to release? I have men, too, in the forest to-night, close behind me, and THEY will be here first and do the releasing."

(a quote from 'Interloper', by Saki.)

In the above sentence, it would be right to understand the *much* as an ellipsis of "much of you"?

Comment: We need more context. From this excerpt, one cannot be sure WHAT is to be released!

Comment: It's neither "right to understand" nor is it "necessary" to do so. *Much* here stands for "anything of significant extent" and that should be good enough for the sentence. Why the question? Can you elaborate? No ellipsis was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lengthier excerpt from "[The Interloper](https://books.google.ca/books?id=fSD0AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&dq=%22Are+you+sure+that+your+men+will+find+much+to+release%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K6MXVZ7tFoHToATO34C4Bw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22Are%20you%20sure%20that%20your%20men%20will%20find%20much%20to%20release%22&f=false)," for context:

> "I'm caught in my own forest-land," retorted Ulrich. "When my men come to release us you will wish, perhaps, that you were in a better plight than caught poaching on a neighbour's land, shame on you."
>
> Georg was silent for a moment; then he answered quietly:
>
> “Are you sure that your men will find much to release? I have men, too, in the forest to-night, close behind me, and *they* will be here first and do the releasing. When they drag me out from under these dmned branches it won't need much clumsiness on their part to roll this mass of trunk right over the top of you. Your men will find you dead under a fallen beech tree. For form's sake I shall send my condolences to your family."

In this exchange, which occurs immediately after a huge beech tree has fallen in a storm, trapping two enemies—Ulrich and Georg—in its branches, Ulrich tells Georg that his men will come and release him from the imprisoning branches, at which point Georg will be in trouble for trespassing. But Georg's response is to ask whether Ulrich's men will "find much [of Ulrich] to release" when they arrive—because by then Georg's men will have arrived, freed Georg, and rolled the trunk of the heavy tree over Ulrich, squashing him like a bug.

So, yes, in the statement by Georg to Ulrich, "much" means "much of you." However, it doesn't mean literally that much of Ulrich will have disappeared, but rather that Ulrich will soon look very different from the way he looks now, or that because Ulrich will be dead, his men won't find much of him worth releasing when they arrive.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, indeed.

This is [a link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=za_EkodPlQgC&pg=PA289&dq=%22Are%20you%20sure%20that%20your%20men%20will%20find%20much%20to%20release%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hNYQVZS1JM73yQTUlIDQDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Are%20you%20sure%20that%20your%20men%20will%20find%20much%20to%20release%22&f=false) (normally required if you want to present the context for helpers).

Comment: It seems the OP's question is whether the implication can be drawn from language alone and not the broader context. There was no ellipsis by the way.